# Reporting Services Permission Management

Tags: reporting-services, reporting

I have a drop-down list and it lists all employees names. When the employee chooses his/her name then report shows all the  infos about the chosen person. However, I want to apply something like this;

-For example, I will give full access to department heads. It means that when they click on to the dropdown-list then, they will be able to see all the employee name list. Other not accessed employees will see just their names in that dropdown list.

How can I manage this?

```
      Employee_Info_View
      ----------------
        NAME             ID
       Employee_A        1
       Employee_B        2
       Employee_C        3
       Employee_D        4
       Employee_E        5
```

For example, I give a permission to Employee_A just for the view his montly performance report. When he opens the report he must see just his name in the name-dropdown-list. In addition, if I give full permission to Employee_B then he must see the all names in that drop-down-list.

Comment: A few questions: Does any of your employee tables have the login user id? Is there a link to the employee and the manager? Can you put a few details of your schema or table/s?

Comment: @glh Every employee has an ID number in the same view table. When I give permission to an employee for a specific report then he/she can see all the employee list from the dropdown list which lists all the employee names. I edited the question above.

Comment: It is difficult to give someone permission to bits of a report unless their details are in a table. See my update below. Also is there a link to the manager and employee? Also there computer userid? These will be important. Nice questio @Omnipotent.

Answer (score 0):

Reporting services can get the currwnt user id. This can the be automatically linked to your employee table to show there info. Use the following in your expression:

```
=User!UserID
```

Also, using this you can see if the user running the report is a manager of other employees and show thoes employees also.

**This method is preferred as the user doesn't need to select a name increasing the reports security.**

**Edit:**

I would expect an employee table to have userid, employee, and manager. Then a query such as:

```
select *
from   employee e, employee m
Where  (e.userid = @userid or m.userid = @userid)
       And e.manager = m.employee
```

If this is not the case then you should set up a table that links the two persons and create a similar query. Again this would then run automatically and improve security.

Then the `@userid` parameter would be `=User!UserID`.

Comment: I didn't get it clearly. Can you explain it more please. Where shall I write this expression?

Comment: When I apply this solution into my report then it needs a new parameter. I should have just one parameter which lists the employee names. When an accesed employee opens the report then he should see all the employee name in this drow-down. Otherwise, another not accessed employee should see just his name in that drop-down list. To sum up, report must have just one parameter to select his name.

Comment: I suspect you have 2 datasets with 2 separate parameters. You will need to have either one feed of the other, that being one generates a list of employees they can see in the drop-down and the other uses the parameter chosen.

Comment: Yes I have two datasets. The second is just created to binding employee names.

Comment: Try and use the label and values properties of the parameter. You can use `.value` and `.label` for two different parameter properties.